# How to reference object in another class

Tags: java, reference

I'm a beginner in java. I have to make shopping cart. 
But I'm stuck on reference.

Please help me!

I tried to make private member variable ShoppingCart in Customer class.
But I think it is not right way.

Customer.java

```
public class Customer {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private ShoppingCart s;

    public Customer(String id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        s = new ShoppingCart();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("Customer ID is: " + this.id + "\n" + "Customer's name is: "
                 + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + "\n\n" 
                + s.toString());

    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Customer c1 = new Customer("12345", "David", "Smith");

        //This sentence doesn't work because of s.
        c1.s.addBooktoCart("Harry Potter", "Fantasy Genre", 10.99, 309);



    }

}
```

ShoppingCart.java

```
public class ShoppingCart {
    private int itemCount;
    private double totalPrice;
    private static int capacity;
    private Item[] cart;
    public ShoppingCart()
    {       
        capacity = 5;
        itemCount = 0;
        totalPrice = 0.0;
        cart = new Item[capacity];
    }

    public void addBooktoCart(String title, String description, double price, int pageCount) {

        if (itemCount < 5) {

        Item item = new Book(title, description, price, pageCount);
        totalPrice += price;
        cart[itemCount] = item;
        itemCount += 1;       
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("The maximum number that you can input is 5." +
                     "You cannot add item anymore");
        }

    }

}
```

I want to call addBooktoCart that is in ShoppingCart class in the Test.java.
But it doesn't work. What do I do if I call addBooktoCart? And If there is another problem. Please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right to `private`.  Just do not refer to field directly. Instead, please use `get/set` method.

```java
c1.getS().addBooktoCart("Harry Potter", "Fantasy Genre", 10.99, 309);
```

By the way, please choose your field name carefully. `s` means nothing.

Comment: Ah! I got it. Can you give me any name? I think that naming the variable name is difficult.

Comment: `cart` is not bad. Just for your reference.

Comment: Worth to mention that this doesn't work with immutable types (like String).

Answer (score 0):

In java by convention, we should keep all variables as private **unless we have any specific reason not to do so**. So , in your case you should keep ShoppingCart as private field in class Customer.Also, while naming variables java follows **naming conventions** :

Refer [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html#naming)

> Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal
>   identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and
>   digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the
>   underscore character "*". The convention, however, is to always begin
>   your variable names with a letter, not "$" or "*". Additionally, the
>   dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all. You may
>   find some situations where auto-generated names will contain the
>   dollar sign, but your variable names should always avoid using it. A
>   similar convention exists for the underscore character; while it's
>   technically legal to begin your variable's name with "_", this
>   practice is discouraged. White space is not permitted.

For your case you can have setter and getter methods for your ShoppingCart to fetch the object and later set it to the instance after your operations like :

**Customer.java**

```
public class Customer {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private ShoppingCart shoppingCart;

    public ShoppingCart getShoppingCart() {
      return shoppingCart;
    }

    public ShoppingCart setShoppingCart(ShoppingCart shoppingCart) {
      this.shoppingCart = shoppingCart;
    }

    public Customer(String id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        s = new ShoppingCart();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("Customer ID is: " + this.id + "\n" + "Customer's name is: "
                 + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + "\n\n" 
                + s.toString());

    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ShoppingCart shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();

        Customer customer = new Customer("12345", "David", "Smith");

        //This sentence doesn't work because of s.
        shoppingCart.addBooktoCart("Harry Potter", "Fantasy Genre", 10.99, 309);
        customer.setShoppingCart(shoppingCart);
    }

}
```